# Fliping a fair coin $3$ times

Tags: probability

Fliping coin $3$ times, let $N$ denote the number of times that we have the same result as the previos flip, and let $i$ be the indicator random variable of the event "not all the $3$ flips are the same (at least one $"T"$ and at least one $"H"$ )"

$(A.)$ Find the common distribotion of $N$ and $i$

$(B.)$ $N$ and $i$ are independent? are they uncorrelated?

$(C.)$ Let $X:=N/(i+1)$, find the expected value of $X$ and the probability that $X$ is smaller from one

---

**My attempt:**

$(A.)$

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
i\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large N}{\phantom{l}} & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4 \\
1 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

$(B.)$ $N$ and $i$ are $\bbox[yellow]{\text{dependent}}$ because that there is zero in the table,

let's check if they are uncorrelated:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr|c}
i\overset{\LARGE\setminus}{\phantom{.}}\overset{\Large N}{\phantom{l}} & 0 & 1 & 2&P_i \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1/4&1/4 \\
1 & 1/4 & 1/2 & 0&3/4 \\
\hline
P_N&1/4&1/2&1/4&1\\
\end{array}
$$

$$E[N]=0\cdot 1/4+1\cdot 1/2+2\cdot1/4=1\\
E[i]=0\cdot 1/4+1\cdot 3/4=3/4\\
E[N]E[i]=3/4$$

let's check $E[Ni]=1/2$

$$\Longrightarrow E[N]E[i]\neq E[Ni]$$ so $N$ and $i$ are $\bbox[yellow]
{\text{correlated}}$.

$(C.)$ $$E[X]=1/2+1/4=3/4\\$$

$P(X<1):$

$$i\in \{1,2\},\quad N\in \{0,1,2\}\\$$

$P(X<1)$ when $0/1$ or $0/2$ or $1/2$

$P(0/1)=0,\quad P(0/2)=1/4,\quad P(1/2)=1/2\\
\Longrightarrow P(X<1)=1/4+1/2=3/4$

My attempt is correct?

Comment: I did not find any errors in your work. What your work lacks in error it makes up for in correctness. Well done. :-)